# JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 error in AWS Lambda

Tags: json, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to write a aws lambda function which will push the SQS queue output in a s3 bucket. 
But the lambda function is failing to push the message , the cloudwatch log is showing

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1
```

i am posting the lambda function which i am using

```
import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
s3 = boto3.client("s3")
data = json.loads(event["Records"][0]["body"]) --getting error in this line 
print(data)
s3.put_object(Bucket="sqsmybucket",key="data.json", Body=json.dumps(data))
#print(event)
return {
    'statusCode': 200,
    'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!') 
}
```

The cloud watch log is showing

```
2020-05-30T23:51:45.276+05:30

[ERROR] JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 6, in lambda_handler
data = json.loads(event["Records"][0]["body"])
 File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
```

I have formatted the message and saved it to the cloud below is the link

```
[formatted JSON code][1]
```

[formatted JSON](https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=local.fafasi&right=cloud.c3ca5edd8f4f41cfad7f8c97c0d93de2)

Please help , thanks in advance

Comment: In your JSON, the "body" attribute is simply the text "A difficult message.", did you replace the real content, or is that really what Lambda processes? If so, since that is not JSON, "json.loads" throwing "JSONDecodeError" is to be expected (see here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `event["Records"][0]["body"]` is a plain string, **not json**:

```
"body": "A difficult message."
```

Therefore, `json.loads(event["Records"][0]["body"])` is equivalent to `json.loads("A difficult message.")` which obviously fails.

To get body's value you can do the following instead:

```
data = event["Records"][0]["body"]
```

However, since later you have the following statment:

```
Body=json.dumps(data)
```

The `Body` will be:

```
Body='"A difficult message."'
```

which may or may not be what you desire.